# Are MX records independent of A records?

Tags: mx

I recently switched a domain's email service to Google. The only records I changed in the name server was the MX records, pointing to Google. To my surprise, emails sent to and from Google Apps work just fine. So is there a point in changing the A, CNAME, and other records in the name server for a domain if the only use of the domain is email?

Comment: I guess the question is what are the A record and CNAME pointing to? Are you (or were you) paying for hosting and that no longer applies?

Answer (score 4):

When you are sending a mail to `aaa@example.com`,The mail server of `example.com` is determined using `MX` records. Assume the following records for example.

```
example.com MX mail.example.com

mail.example.com A 1.2.3.4
```

If an `MX` record is found, `MTA` will do a forward lookup for the name returned (here `mail.example.com` which will return `1.2.3.4` )and try to deliver the mail to `1.2.3.4`. If no `MX` record is found for the domain and only the following DNS records exist

```
example.com A 1.2.3.5
```

`MTAs` will try to connect to `A` record of the domain itself, (here `1.2.3.5`) and try to deliver the mail. only when no `MX` record exist for that domain.`A` record will be used. Hope this clarifies why just changing `MX` records worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

MX records are used by and for mail servers so email can be exchanged.

Changing a domain to use Google Apps for email service only requires changing all the mail related DNS entries.

A and CNAME records are used to convert people friendly URL's into IP addresses.

If you have a CNAME record for mail.yourdomain.com, you are better off changing it too but if no one opens a page to that URL it might not matter.

A and CNAME records for any other part of the domain (web pages for example) should remain unchanged.